# Testing and mocking a call with jest not working

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test the following function:

```
// playlist.js
export function getSimplePlaylist() {
  // something here
}

export function getPlaylist(type, settings) {
  let options = { type };

  if (type === 'simple') {
    options.getData = () => {
      const { videos } = settings;
      return getSimplePlaylist(videos);
    };
  }
   // There are few more cases here, but no need to post them
 return options;
}
```

I have tried a bunch of different ways of testing that, but no luck, i.e:

```
//playlist.spec.js
import * as playlist from '.';
describe('getPlaylist', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('should get correct option when static ', () => {
    playlist.getSimplePlaylist = jest.fn();
    const videos = playlist.getPlaylist('simple', { videos: [1, 2, 3] });
    videos.getData()
    expect(playlist.getSimplePlaylist).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Any ideas on how I can test something like the above? Thanks!

Comment: getSimplePlaylist is not a member of the playlist so you cannot mock it that way

Comment: Ah, sorry missed to put it in there. But it is part of the playlist.js file

Answer (score 0):

If you use the function that way you use the JS functional programming. `getPlayList` will always call original `getSimplePlaylist`. If you want to do it you should use class:

```js
class Playlist {
  def() {
    return 'def';
  }

  abc(cond) {
    if (cond) {
      return this.def();
    }
  }
}

export default Playlist;
```

and then you could test it:

```js
import Playlist from './playlist';

describe('Name of the group', () => {
  it('should ', () => {
    const play = new Playlist();
    play.def = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('mock');
    expect(play.abc(true)).toEqual('mock');
    expect(play.def).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

or you could use function with default implementation and then in test pass additional parameter:

```js
// playlist.js
export function getSimplePlaylist() {
  // something here
}

export function getPlaylist(type, settings, simplePlaylistFunc=getSimplePlaylist) {
  let options = { type };

  if (type === 'simple') {
    options.getData = () => {
      const { videos } = settings;
      return simplePlaylistFunc(videos);
    };
  }
   // There are few more cases here, but no need to post them
 return options;
}
```

Comment: I think that makes sense, might need to use second option then. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution here to mock function in a file would be to not export them individually but from an object and use it from that object in the particular module

```
// playlist.js
function getSimplePlaylist() {
  // something here
}

function getPlaylist(type, settings) {
  let options = { type };

  if (type === 'simple') {
    options.getData = () => {
      const { videos } = settings;
      return funcs.getSimplePlaylist(videos);
    };
  }
   // There are few more cases here, but no need to post them
 return options;
}

const funcs = {
    getSimplePlaylist,
    getPlaylist
}

export default funcs;
```

Now you can test them like

```
//playlist.spec.js
import playlist from '.';
describe('getPlaylist', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('should get correct option when static ', () => {
    playlist.getSimplePlaylist = jest.fn();
    const videos = playlist.getPlaylist('simple', { videos: [1, 2, 3] });
    videos.getData()
    expect(playlist.getSimplePlaylist).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: I think this looks better, than the other solution. Let me try doing it that way, thanks!